# Mean separation equivalent for a test of equal variance

Tags: variance, multiple-comparisons, levenes-test

I am working on a project where consistency the most important factor. It involves a 4 input risk rating system. I am interested in what inputs are the most variable/sensitive to assessor bias.

When doing ANOVA and finding the main effect is significant, the next logical step is mean separation of some fashion to see what levels are different from each other (using Fisher LSD, Tukeys, Scheffe, contrasts, etc, etc).

Is there an equivalent to the above for tests of equal variance like Bartlett's, Levenes, or Fligner-Killeen? While simply knowing one of the 4 variances is different is a start, it really doesn't help with my question. One can infer by referencing boxplots / violin graphs, but I was hoping for a means of statistically separating out the variances from most to least variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could conduct all pairwise comparisons using a test of your choice, and then apply the Holm-Bonferroni procedure on the set of p-values that your have obtained. This should ensure that your family-wise error rate does not exceed α.

Comment: Thanks, Benedict. That was exactly the direction I was thinking of going. This helps me in proceeding. I searched quite a bit in my books and online to find something more elegant, but it doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: Thank you. I would be interested in a "specialized" method myself, but the approaches I have encountered were inadequate. The only drawback with the HB procedure that I am aware of is power; but then again we are not burdened by the assumption of independent hypotheses. I added the "multiple comparisons" tag to your post in the hope of attracting more answers.